# Convert normal keyboard into Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: arduino-uno, bluetooth, keyboard

I am very new to the Arduino world, I am trying to convert my wired keyboard into a bluetooth keyboard. I have a few layman questions:

- Is it possible to add an audio jack adapter(like PS4 joystick has), so that I can plugin my headphones to my keyboard itself to listen to the music.
- Is it possible to achieve this(bluetooth keyboard + audio jack) on Arduino or do I need to use Rasberry-pi?
- Is there a way to keep my current USB wire? so that I can keep working even if the battery runs out.
- I want to keep all the apparatus in the keyboard casing itself, can you please suggest smallest Arduino board that will work for my use case.
- I am not sure if I need a special kind of bluetooth breakout board for this(that can receive audio as input and send keystrokes to my system). Can you please guide what will be the best fit board.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I want to keep all the apparatus in the keyboard casing itself` - can you be specific about how much room you have in your keyboard casing - because if it's anything like mine, you won't find anything that will fit

Comment: @JaromandaX It's a custom made keyboard, I can fit at least something of iPhone7's height and half of it's width in my casing.